# Trying to access Facebook friendlist, but getting a empty friends list

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    FB.api(response.id+'/friends', function(response) {
        for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
            FB.api('/'+response.data[i].id, function(response) {
            {

            }
            });
        }         
    });
});
```

not able to get any list response.data[i].id the length is zero

Answer (score 1):

The call to `/me/friends` will only return the friends which are also using your app, not all friends.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0